# Can generator be used through polymorphism

Tags: python, generator

I don't even know if it is the proper way to put it, but I recently had trouble while trying to use a method from an object, both as a map engine (mapping closure to elements of an iterator) and as a generator of generator.

I is probably much more simple to explain this through a code example:

```
class maybe_generator():
    def __init__(self, doer):
        self.doer = doer

    def give(self):
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            self.doer(i)


def printer(x):
    print('This is {}'.format(x))
def gener(x):
    yield(x)

p = maybe_generator(printer)
p.give()

g = maybe_generator(gener)

print('Type of result is {}'.format(g.give()))
```

Output is

```
This is 1
This is 2
This is 3
Type of result is None
```

I would have expected the g object ot be of type generator instead of NoneType. Then I wonder how it is possible to implement a function that can potentially generate a generator, or directly perform some border effect on the iterable.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This is because your function `give` does not return anything. `self.doer(i)` indeed creates a generator that can yield a single element, but it just throws it away. I'm sorry, but it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What is it you want to to with that? You might just want to use `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what I was looking for. having a function that works both as a mapping engine and a genrator may be possible with some hacks/tricks, but what I wanted in my use case was essentially getting a recursive generator.

This can be easily done with the keyword

> yield from

The code now looks like something like that:

```
class maybe_generator():
    def __init__(self, doer):
        self.doer = doer

    def give(self):
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            yield from self.doer(i)

def gener(x):
    yield(x)

g = maybe_generator(gener)
gen = g.give()
print('Type of result is {}'.format(gen))

for k in gen:
    print('value is {}'.format(k))
```

It was actually also worth taking a look at this advanced series of course on generator and coroutines: http://dabeaz.com/coroutines/